# Date not displayed properly in the nib file

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string with value @"15/11/13". I need to display the same on the label in the nib file. 
I am using the following code to display it

```
NSDateFormatter * df1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
[df1 setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[df1 setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[profile1 setLastPromotionDate:[df1 dateFromString:@"11/11/13"]];
```

Profile1 is a different class which has `lastPromotonDate` of type `NSDate`.
In the nib file I have a outlet to display date which is bound to `lastPromotionDate`.

When I run the app, the date displayed is **Monday, 11 November 2013 12:00:00 AM** India Standard Time.

Can I know what is the mistake here? What has to be done so the date displays in this format : 11/11/13

Comment: Why are you using date formatter to display a string on label. If you already have the string value of date, just use [label setStringValue: yourString];

Comment: This includes a server request , in which we have the date. So we need to set the date and display it on the label. Kindly let me know, if we set lastPromotionDate and bind it to text field, wont it display the date?

Comment: Is the date from server is in string format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have something called **DateFormatter** under objects in the library. We can drag and drop that under the text cell if the label in the list view of the nib. 
This data formatter converts the date format to string value which is used to display in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = @"15/11/13";

// here we create NSDateFormatter object for change the Format of date..

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;

// here set format of date which is in your output date (means above str with format)

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yy/mm/dd"];

// here you can fetch date from string with define format

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: str];

dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;

// here set format which you want..

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yy"];

NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

//here convert date in NSString
NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",convertedString);

rofile1.text = convertedString;
```

Comment: It doesn work. I tried this. It still shows the long format. Is binding causing any issues? and also the lastPromationDate is dynamically populated.

Comment: I edit my answer. I replace MM by mm now check it out

Comment: @ManojUdupa i test it on my code it's work fine can you set your lable text like that profile1.text = convertedString;

Comment: now do one thing paste my hole code on your app and set lable text as i doing in my edit code.

Comment: I am not setting in the code. The label has value binding which is bound to lastPromotionDAte which is of type NSDate. SO whenever we set the value to the profile , it automatically updates the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
NSString *dateStr=@"11/11/13";
NSDateFormatter *format=[[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
[format setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yy"];
NSDate *dt=[format dateFromString:dateStr];
NSString *str=[format stringFromDate:dt];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Comment: i need to check how you are implemnting after merging above code??

Comment: The textfield is value bound to lastPromotionDate which is of type  NSDate. So whatever value the lastPromotionDae has, it shows that value.

Comment: In your textfield set date string Value inspite of setting date. Means change your NSDate *lastPromotionDate to NSString *lastPromotionDate

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set it as:

```
NSString *str = @"15/11/13";
[label setStringValue: str];
```

UPDATE:

To convert this string to NSDate of the same format use:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yy"];
NSDate * date = [df dateFromString:str];
```

To get back the string value of date from NSDate use:

```
NSString *dateStr = [df stringFromDate: date];
```

Also you may use this dateStr to set you label text as

```
[label setStringValue: dateStr];
```

or bind the label to "dateStr". (Do not bind it to "date" of NSDate type, I think this is where you are going wrong).

Use "date" variable that is of NSDate type for your server requests.

UPDATE:

Since you are binding your label to NSDate value, it displays the complete date in the way it is present in NSDate. To retrieve the value of that NSDate in your custom format, you need to use NSDateFormatter that will write the part of NSDate that we need in our format to a NSString.

Also if we convert a NSString to NSDate, it doesn't mean that date formatter will save the NSDate in our custom format, the format of the date formatter specify the format of our string so that NSDate could read the correct date from our custom formatted string. But NSDate will always save the date value in its own format.

Comment: Its just simple. I am setting the date using a specific format,assigning it to a variable of type nsdate. the textfield which displays date is bound to this variable.

Comment: I just wanted know if we bind NSDate variable to textfield, will it work. Looks like it will not. That is the summary right?

Comment: Yes because the date displayed in your code is the format in which NSDate saves a date. DateFormatter cannot change NSDate type. It just changes the format in which NSDate could read or write to.

Comment: So if you take the value from NSDate itself it will always display the complete date

Comment: Thnx. That makes sense. I thought if we bind the NSDate to label, NSDate's description method might get called to display the date which is not true.